# Page numbering starts too early

Tags: page-numbering

As the title already indicates, I have a problem with the page numbering.

At first I am in roman numbering mode and then I switch to arabic. But even though my `\pagenumbering{arabic}` statement is *after* my `\listoftables` command, the list of tables has the pagenumber **1**.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,headsepline,footsepline,DIV13,BCOR12mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc,numberedsection]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{fap}{FAP}{Fundamental Architectural Principles}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hspace{0.7cm} &
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\vspace{8mm}
\begin{center}
{\Large
{\bfseries \scshape Institut Software \&  Engineering}\\
 6a \hspace{0.25cm} D- \\
}
\end{center}

\vspace{1cm}
%title
\begin{center}
{\Huge \bfseries asd  \\[2mm] in   \\[5mm] asdasd }
\end{center}

\vspace{1.5cm}
%author
\begin{center}
{\Large Christian Vaas}
\end{center}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{center}
{\Large \bfseries Masterarbeit  Software Engineering}
\end{center}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{img/logos/LogoSEengl}
\end{center}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hspace{0.7cm} &
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{center}
{\Large
{\bfseries \scshape Institut Software \& Systems Engineering}\\
 6a \hspace{0.25cm} D- \\
}
\end{center}

\vspace{2.5cm}
%title
\begin{center}
{\Huge \bfseries  Patterns \\[2mm] in   \\[5mm]  Architectures}
\end{center}

\vspace{1cm}
%author
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Matrikelnummer: &  \\
Beginn der Arbeit: & XX.\ X. XXX 20XX \\ 
Abgabe der Arbeit: & XX.\ X.XXX 20XX \\
Erstgutachter: & Prof.\ Dr.\ \\
Zweitgutachter: & Prof.\ Dr.\ YYY YYYYYY \\
Betreuer: &  S.  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{center}

\vspace{1.25cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Statement-Page
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\centerline{\bfseries ERKLAERUNG}

\vspace{5cm}
Hiermit versichere ich, dass ich diese Masterarbeit selbstaendig verfasst habe.
Ich habe dazu keine anderen als die angegebenen Quellen und Hilfsmittel
verwendet.

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{flushleft}
%select german for formatting the date
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
Augsburg, den \today \hfill ZZZ ZZZZZZ
\end{flushleft}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}


\newpage

%select english as language!
\selectlanguage{english}

\vspace*{1cm}
\section*{\centering Abstract}
\vspace{1cm}

\paragraph*{CONTEXT}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Motivation/Challenges}
\section{Approach}
Blubber \gls{fap}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add another `\newpage` between `\listoftables` and `\pagenumbering{arabic}`.

Answer (score 4):

As mafp already mentioned in his comment, adding a `\newpage` statement fixes my problem. :-)